# Receive String in Spring Boot SOAP Endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap

I need to create an Endpoint in Spring-boot to receive a SOAP request, but I need that request be a Java String. I have something like that:

Config:

```
@Bean(name = "myService")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition receiveM2Definition(XsdSchema mySchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new 
        DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("testPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/my");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://test/me");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(mySchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
}
```

Endpoint:

```
@PayloadRoot(
namespace       = "http://test/me", 
localPart       = "getMyRequest"
)
@ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<String> getReq(@RequestPayload 
JAXBElement<String> request) {
 .......   }
```

This work fine, but I need that my endpoint receives a String for my client instead of a JAXBElement.
Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `getValue` on the `JAXBElement`.

Comment: @M.Deinum the problem is that the client sends me a String instead of a JAXBElement, I need to adapt my enpoint to receive that String.

Comment: Ofcourse it is a String... The whole HTTP stuff is String based. If he sends you a String then what is the purpose of even building a SOAP web service? There is contract in there and your client should honor that. That string represents your XML.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes i think like you, if my client send me a simple string what is the purpose of even building a SOAP web service, but in this case, i build the server but my server must adapt to the client and not the opposite. And the client what is going to send me is a String with a XML inside. I have no idea how to make my endpoint receive the Payload as a String.

Comment: As stated of course it is a String... The whole HTTP message is a string so basically everything is a string. You are getting to much hung up what the client is sending. Bottom line is he is sending XML and apparently you have decided on a contract else what is the purpose of this SOAP endpoint?

Comment: Have you tried `getReq(@RequestPayload String request)`?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in my Schema.xsd work fine:

```
<!-- Operations -->
<xs:element name="getRequest" type="xs:string">
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="getResponse" type="xs:string">
</xs:element>
```